# Stream of items, each producing n{ http request } > merge{response} > wrapInHeaderAndFooter{data} > http-request

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to solve a classic ETL problem using streaming. I have a batch of segments, Each segment holds information about the records associated for that segment like number of records, url to retrieve etc, to issue a http request to collect data. I need to extract the records from a source with paging size of 100 records, merge the pages of records for each segment, wrap in a xml header and footer. Now send each xml payload per segment to a target.

```
                 {http}
                 page 1
                 /      \
       seg 1 >  page 2  -> merge -> wrapHeaderAndFooter -> http target 
          /      \      /
         /       page n
        / 
       /
batch -  seg 2                    "                     -> http target
       \ seg n                    "                     -> http target
```

```
val loadSegment: Flow[Segment, Response, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[Segment].mapAsync(parallelism = 5) { segment =>
      val pages: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = pagedPayload(segment).map(page => page.payload)
//Using source concatenation to prepend and append
      val wrappedInXML: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = xmlRootStartTag ++ pages ++ xmlRootEndTag
      val httpEntity: HttpEntity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, pages)
        invokeTargetLoad(httpEntity, request, segment)
    }
  }
def pagedPayload(segment: Segment): Source[Payload, NotUsed] = {
    val totalPages: Int =   calculateTotalPages(segment.instanceCount)
      Source(0 until totalPages).mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism = 5)(i => {
        sendPayloadRequest(request, segment, i).mapTo[Try[Payload]].map(_.get)
      })
  }

val batch: Batch = someBatch
  Source(batch.segments)
    .via(loadSegment)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
    .andThen {
      case Success(value) => log("success")
      case Failure(error) => report(error)
    }
```

Is there a better approach? I am trying to use the `HttpEntity.Chunked` encoding to stream the pages. Sometimes the first request from the source can take longer time due to warm up and the target truncates the stream with no data. Is there a way to delay the actual connection to target until we have the first page in stream?

I would have more liked to do something like below. if it's possible how to implement methods **wrapXMLHeader** & **toHttpEntity**

```
val splitPages: Flow[BuildSequenceSegment, Seq[PageRequest], NotUsed] = ???
  val requestPayload: Flow[Seq[PageRequest], Seq[PageResponse], NotUsed] = ???
  val wrapXMLHeader: Flow[Seq[PageResponse], Seq[PageResponse], NotUsed] = ???
  val toHttpEntity: Flow[Seq[PageResponse], HttpEntity.Chunked, NotUsed] = ???
  val invokeTargetLoad: Flow[HttpEntity.Chunked, RestResponse, NotUsed] = ???

  Source(batch.segments)
    .via(splitPages)
    .via(requestPayload)
    .via(wrapXMLHeader)
    .via(toHttpEntity)
    .via(invokeTargetLoad)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```